# Genymotion android emulator on WIndows 8

Tags: android, windows-8, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I have got windows 7 and windows 8 on my laptop, and install genymotion on both OS's.  On Windows 7, it run fine. On Windows 8, the emulator looks like its starting fine and opens, but then i get a message saying "Unable to connect to your virtual device. Genymotion will now stop. Check your VirtualBox network connections". Pressing Ok shuts down the emulator.

I have opened Oracle VirtualBox and opens Preferences > Network and have both tabs setup with the same ip addresses on both OS's.  Settings below.

[image: Adaptor Tab]

[image: DHCP Tab]

I can open the image directly from Oracle VirtualBox, so there must be something funny.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simple Go **Setting** > **Misc** and **Clear cache** . And try to run again hope you will not face the problem again see the image